# How to implement clinic.js in Nest JS Framework (typescript)

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-jwt

I implemented Clinic.js in Node JS. But I don't know how to implement clinic.js in Nest JS Framework. I explore it how to implement clinic.js to Nest JS. But I couldn't get any answer can you please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

`nest start` will transpile TS files into JS then run JS code. Thats why this is not working with clinicJS. You should find a `dist` folder, with good JS files.

using `yarn build` to transpiling your TS file to JS, then use `clinic docker -- node dist/main`. it using nodejs run endpoint file (main.ts).

Answer (score -1):

I know nothing about [Clinic.js](https://www.clinicjs.org/), but from taking a quick look through their docs, it looks like you can just do `clinic doctor -- nest start --watch` and it should pick up on the running server

Comment: I run this command  it's throwing an error. this command where to i config in nest js. can you please tell me.

Error
Clinic.js must be called with a `node` command line: `clinic doctor -- node script.js`

Comment: Can you please suggest any other profiling tool and provide some implementation documentation using in nest js. I tried to explorer how to implement profiling in nest js it but I could not get it because I am new in this framework